# .pause() doesn't work with multiple MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, onpause

I have multiple MediaPlayers and I want to pause them using independent buttons.I didn't have any problems with another application with a single MediaPlayer, but now the method ".pause" is giving me problems.

In Logs can be viewed that the method ".isPlaying" is working fine, but the video doesn't pause.I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

When I click the button for the first time, pause, I obtain this Logs:

```
07-12 15:08:59.786: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(1562): isPlaying: 1
07-12 15:08:59.786: I/MediaPlayer(1562): sendBroadcast SMART_PAUSE_stop()
07-12 15:08:59.786: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(1562): stop
07-12 15:08:59.786: V/MediaPlayer(1562): stop
07-12 15:08:59.786: V/MediaPlayer(1562): message received msg=7, ext1=0, ext2=0
07-12 15:08:59.786: V/MediaPlayer(1562): unrecognized message: (7, 0, 0)
07-12 15:08:59.786: V/MediaPlayer(1562): callback application
07-12 15:08:59.786: V/MediaPlayer(1562): back from callback
07-12 15:08:59.826: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(1562): getCurrentPosition: 5080 (msec)
07-12 15:08:59.826: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(1562): isPlaying: 0
```

The second time, resume, I obtain this Logs:

```
07-12 15:08:24.501: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(1562): isPlaying: 0
07-12 15:08:24.506: I/MediaPlayer(1562): sendBroadcast SMART_PAUSE_start()
07-12 15:08:24.506: W/MediaPlayer(1562): this is IMEDIA_PLAYER_VIDEO_EXIST
07-12 15:08:24.506: I/MediaPlayer(1562): sendBroadcast android.media.IMediaPlayer.videoexist
07-12 15:08:24.506: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(1562): start
07-12 15:08:24.506: V/MediaPlayer(1562): start
07-12 15:08:24.506: E/MediaPlayer(1562): start called in state 64
07-12 15:08:24.506: V/MediaPlayer(1562): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
07-12 15:08:24.506: E/MediaPlayer(1562): error (-38, 0)
07-12 15:08:24.506: V/MediaPlayer(1562): callback application
07-12 15:08:24.506: V/MediaPlayer(1562): back from callback
07-12 15:08:24.506: E/MediaPlayer(1562): Error (-38,0)
07-12 15:08:24.506: D/MediaPlayer(1562): MediaPlayer(0): onCompletion called
```

What could be the problem?

My code is:

```
public class Reproductor extends Activity implements
    OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener,
    OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnClickListener {

private Bundle extras;
private static final String PATH = "path";
private static final String PATH2 = "path2";
private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayer";
private int[] SURFACE_RES_IDS = { 
    R.id.video_1_surfaceview, R.id.video_2_surfaceview};

private MediaPlayer[] mMediaPlayers = new MediaPlayer[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
private SurfaceView[] mSurfaceViews = new SurfaceView[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
private SurfaceHolder[] mSurfaceHolders = new SurfaceHolder[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
private boolean[] mSizeKnown = new boolean[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
private boolean[] mVideoReady = new boolean[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;
private Button bPlayPause1, bPlayPause2, bMute1, bMute2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.repr_multiple);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    mVideoWidth=1200;
    mVideoHeight=900;
    bPlayPause1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bPlayPause1);
    bPlayPause2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bPlayPause2);
    bMute1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMute1);
    bMute2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMute2);

    bPlayPause1.setOnClickListener(this);
    bPlayPause2.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMute1.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMute2.setOnClickListener(this);

    // create surface holders
     for (int i=0; i<mSurfaceViews.length; i++) {
        mSurfaceViews[i] = (SurfaceView) findViewById(SURFACE_RES_IDS[i]);
        mSurfaceHolders[i] = mSurfaceViews[i].getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolders[i].addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolders[i].setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    }
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer player, int percent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player)
            + "): onBufferingUpdate percent: " + percent);
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player) + "): onCompletion called");
}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer player, int width, int height) {
    Log.v(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player)
            + "): onVideoSizeChanged called");
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height
                + ")");
        return;
    }

    int index = indexOf(player);
    if (index == -1)
        return; // sanity check; should never happen
    mSizeKnown[index] = true;

    if (mVideoReady[index] && mSizeKnown[index]) {
        startVideoPlayback(player);
    }
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player) + "): onPrepared called");

    int index = indexOf(player);
    if (index == -1)
        return; // sanity check; should never happen
    mVideoReady[index] = true;
    startVideoPlayback(player);
    /*
    if (mVideoReady[index] && mSizeKnown[index]) {
        startVideoPlayback(player);
    }
    */
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int i, int j, int k) {
    Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceHolder(" + indexOf(holder)
            + "): surfaceChanged called");
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceHolder(" + indexOf(holder)
            + "): surfaceDestroyed called");
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceHolder(" + indexOf(holder)
            + "): surfaceCreated called");

    int index = indexOf(holder);
    if (index == -1)
        return; // sanity check; should never happen
    try {
        mMediaPlayers[index] = new MediaPlayer();
        if(index == 0){
            mMediaPlayers[index].setDataSource(extras.getString(PATH));
        }else if(index == 1){
            mMediaPlayers[index].setDataSource(extras.getString(PATH2));
        }else{
            mMediaPlayers[index].setDataSource(extras.getString(PATH2));
        }
        mMediaPlayers[index].setDisplay(mSurfaceHolders[index]);
        mMediaPlayers[index].setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayers[index].prepareAsync();
        mMediaPlayers[index].setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayers[index].setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayers[index].setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayers[index].setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
  //  releaseMediaPlayers();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayers();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mMediaPlayers.length; i++) {
        if (mMediaPlayers[i] != null) {
            mMediaPlayers[i].release();
            mMediaPlayers[i] = null;
        }
    }
}

private void startVideoPlayback(MediaPlayer player) {
    Log.v(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player) + "): startVideoPlayback");
    player.start();
}

private int indexOf(MediaPlayer player) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mMediaPlayers.length; i++)
        if (mMediaPlayers[i] == player)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

private int indexOf(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSurfaceHolders.length; i++)
        if (mSurfaceHolders[i] == holder)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bPlayPause1:
        if(mMediaPlayers[0].isPlaying()){
            mMediaPlayers[0].pause();  
            bPlayPause1.setText("Resume");
        }else{
            mMediaPlayers[0].start();
            bPlayPause1.setText("Pause");
        }                                               
        break;
    case R.id.bPlayPause2:
        if(mMediaPlayers[1].isPlaying()){
            mMediaPlayers[1].pause();
            bPlayPause2.setText("Resume");
        }else{
            mMediaPlayers[1].start();
            bPlayPause2.setText("Pause");
        }
        break;
    case R.id.bMute1:
        break;
    case R.id.bMute2:
        break;          
    }
  }
}
```